# AWStats Temp File Write Permissions Issue

Tags: awstats

I'm having an issue with AWStats updating its temporary database.  I have the call to update the reporting database every hour through launchd, which runs as root.  The perl scripts are called, and nothing gets updated.  Troubleshooting demonstrated the following warning:

> Warning: Failed to rename "/tmp/awstats082013.food.tmp.1641" into "/tmp/awstats082013.food.txt".
>   Write permissions on "awstats082013.food.txt" might be wrong or file might be opened.

The permissions on that file is 777.  The permissions on /tmp are also 777.  Why AWStats cannot modify that file is really the question.  I can do this manually using sudo, but the bash script that is run hourly by launchd shouldn't have to take the sudo -A, nor does it work.

Any advice as to how I can push through this, is appreciated.

Comment: `or file might be opened.` Close Apache, the file is in use, other than that try chown www-data:www-data tmp

Comment: By what?  AWStats is the executable that created it.  It's trying to write to the file it has created itself. That's what an update does.

Comment: thought you was using the frontend of awstats, php. ,my bad didn't read fully.

Comment: Actually using both.  You can use the perl directly to update the stats, or a link that does the same.  Same permissions warning in both instances.  AWStats creates that temp db of its own in both cases, and I have no clue why.

Comment: Solved: set ownership to root:admin and "sodo launchctl load item.plist".  Ya mon.  Very happy.

Comment: You shouldn't need to run as root, that's insecure. You should just chown the file to the user running the script or share usergroup with that group.

Comment: It wouldn't run without sudo.  Tested many times.  It was chown to root:admin.  So it's still running as root, as launchd runs as root.

Comment: OK, it's back to the same warning again.  Nothing has changed, ownership of the bash script is root:admin.  Everything is pretty clear.  Can't rename a temp file due to permissions (see above).